# How can I test memory optimized tables using tSQLt?

Tags: tsqlt

Currently, when I try to unit test stored procedures using **tSQLt**, if my test touches a Memory Optimized table, I receive the following error:

```
(Error) Creating a savepoint is not supported with memory optimized tables.[16,98]
(There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. 
 Roll back the entire transaction.{Private_RunTest,161})
```

I cannot find any docs in the wiki or elsewhere online that show the usage of In Memory tables with **tSQLt**, or a way to get around this issue.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tSQLt currently requires the ability to rollback to a savepoint to work. However, savepoints are not compatible with MO tables, as the error states.

I will look into options to change this, but that will require a major rework of the tSQLt engine, so I can't make any promises right now.